# Acessar site na SMARTTV

Tags: html5, css3

Olá, 
Desenvolvi um sistema web em php/html/css(Bootstrap) e abrir normal em vários dispositivos pc, notebooks, tablets, celulares porém em TV's Smart, que é o foco do sistema, não ficou legal não reconhece altura dos elementos, a tag svg não apareceu, enfim um série de bugs.

Alguém já passou por isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existe uma lista de tv's que o html5 é suportado:

LG WebOS 2016   WebOS
Samsung Smart TV 2015   Tizen
Panasonic Viera 2015    Firefox OS
GoogleTV    Chrome 11

Confira se sua tv esta nas suportadas, além de possuir notas para cada tv em seu suporte. Apenas estas conseguiram interpretar bem um site como o seu.

Fonte: https://html5test.com/results/other.html

Comment: Obrigado pelo retorno Luiz, vamos ter que repensar o sistema, não tem como prever qual TV vai ter no cliente.